# Realizing Transaction Management in Mule with self developed connector and java component

Tags: mule, mule-component

I'm new to Mule and have a few general questions about transaction management in Mule 3.5. First of all here is the scenario flow using XA transaction :
JMS Connector ----> Java Component ---> self-defined Connector ----> Database Connector

Questions:

1. How do i put my Java component in the same transaction context? For example I have an operation that persist something in a file or change something in a database but only if the transaction succeeds. Do I have to define an exception strategy or is there another way?
2. How do i put my self-defined connector in a transaction context, so that it can be configured from Mule like the JMS oder database connector?

Thank you

Comment: I'm in what appears to be the same boat; my flow takes messages from a JMS connector and passes them through a Java component, and this needs to be transactioned. You know, given that yours is just about the only hit on Google, it would seem that Java components cannot participate in XA transactions -- otherwise _someone_ would have written _something_ about it. It's just too bad that _MuleSoft don't say so_ in their documentation.